# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, release-management

I want to upgrade from ubuntu 10.10 to ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Relevant for anyone who (thinks they) want to do an upgrade of such old versions *these days*: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press `Alt+F2` and type `update-manager`, this should show the option to upgrade to 11.04.

Through the terminal this can be done using the same command but I am guessing you need use **sudo** to do this.

Answer (score 18):

The truly command line way is (e.g. if you don't have a gui):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: It says no new release found. I am running 10.04

Comment: @sarat That's because 10.04 is a Long Term release.. You can follow these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Network%20Upgrade%20for%20Ubuntu%20Servers%20%28Recommended%29

Answer (score 7):

The official ubuntu.com page has information:

- For [desktop and server editions](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade).

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Open the Software Sources application from the System -> Administration menu
2. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application:

   [image]
3. Change the Release Update drop down to "Normal Releases" and close the application
4. Open Update Manager from the System -> Administration menu
5. Click the Check button to check for new updates.
6. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
7. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

   [image: upgrade]
8. Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

Taken from:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades

If you're moving from 10.04, see this question:

- [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-04-or-10-10-to-11-04)

Answer (score 4):

From 11.04 onwards,when you boot the livecd and start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 11.04. it will automatically detect installed apps and install the updated version of your apps also.
assuming your 
not dual booting

[image: live CD : Allocate drive space]

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1104-natty.html)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for an upgrade:

1. Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + F2

   then you see a run small command windows

   Then press"update-manager"in run windows

   Now you see many windows just click them and you will upgrade

Comment: What's the difference with the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22747/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-10-to-11-04/22748#22748)?