# Upgrade 10.10 to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22747/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-10-to-11-04)

I wonder, is it safe upgrade 10.10 to 11.04, probably sometimes upgrade gives problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is yes. For most people the update process will work seamlessly.

There are however always risks. A driver in the new version could be not working as good with your hardware as the previous version. Or something in the upgrade process could be going wrong.

For package conflicts you don't have to worry. If they occur, the upgrade will just stop and restore your system.

If you are talking about a great number of pc's (so, in a company) it is off course smart to test it on your hardware configurations and in your environment instead of blindly updating the first day.

Answer (score 2):

Usually upgrades worked fine for me but it's always possible that there are some problems, especially if you are using a lot of 3rd party software (like PPAs).

Some things that could help to minimise trouble:

- See the ["Known Issues" section of the release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes#Known%20Issues) for known problems
- Before upgrading use a live system to check for hardware compatibility problems
- Make a system backup before you upgrade so you can easily go back if you don't like the new version
- Usually there are a lot of bug fix updates during the first few weeks after a release. It may be worth waiting 3 or 4 weeks before upgrading